# Why is Application.OnStartup not being called?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0

I have a WPF .NET 4 application where I override the `OnStartup` method in order to process the file passed to my application. However, it seems that this method is not being called when the application runs. I put an exception in there and even a breakpoint and it starts up and completely ignores this.

Am I missing something?

Code for App.xml.cs:

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for App.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Contents of App.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="XGN_Image_Downloader.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>

</Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**EDIT:** Found it! The x:Class attribute in App.xaml did not match the App.xaml.cs class :) That's what you get for coding while drinking wine. (Thanks to this thread: [WPF app startup problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874920/wpf-app-startup-problems))

Comment: Couldn't repro with just this info.  I created a WPF app, pasted your code over the existing App code-behind, put a debug break on the throw line, ran it, and the debugger broke on that statement.  Can you post your other app-related code?  Possibly app.xaml?

Comment: Do you have multiple projects in your solution? Whether this project is set as startup project?

Comment: The other project is a class library. There are only 2 projects in the solution. This project is set as the startup project. Besides my app.xaml I only have a single main window with nothing fancy in it.

Comment: Try putting an empty constructor `public App() { }` with a breakpoint or an exception.  Is your application object even being created?

Comment: I did that, didn't break, but I found the error in my ways. Solution edited onto the post ;)

Comment: @Jonas Van der Aa: When you can, post an answer to this question with the answer. Then when you can make your own answer as accepted. This will mean that anyone else coming here will be able to see that there was an accepted answer to this question. It will also mean that people who have the same issue may vote your answer up :)

Comment: Done. I planned to but I was commuting and had no internet access :)

Comment: FYI came here because of the same error but realised I forgot to add override to the functino declaration.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Found it, I had to set the `x:Class` attribute in App.xaml to the same class as the App.xaml.cs class. This was an error caused by bad refactoring on my side.

Comment: I've come to this late but was having the same problem even though my x:Class attribute was fine. It seems OnStartup also doesn't fire if your project doesn't have a "startup item" specified in the properties. The application still starts, just doesn't fire on startup.

Answer (score 1):

x:Class must be filled with the namespace and exact class name on App.xml.cs

Eg:   `<Application x:Class="Namespace.ClassName"`